# c# database connection string issue

Tags: sql, visual-studio, local-database

When the code is running. it launches fine, the form if filled out and the submit button is clicked generates a connection error.
I believe it is to do with the connection credentials.
Can someone tell me or confirm what the data source should be for a local machine and should the database have the .mdf after?

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data source=LocalDB; Database=UserData.mdf;User Id=admin; Password=123");
```

Comment: What database are you connecting to?  Outside of code, if you were to directly interact with the database, how specifically would you connect to it?

Comment: Who created the SQL Server Instance? What database name did you/they use when creating it? are you sure SQL Server authentication is used (as opposed to Windows Integrated). Normally there is no extension like .mdf in the database name.

Comment: It is a created local database

Comment: What is the best method for creating a local database?